# jqxGrid with SQL Binding and LargeJsonResult is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqxgrid

I'm having an issue getting a jqxGrid to work with my SQL data binding and a largejsonresult.  Here is my current code.

Controller:

```
public LargeJsonResult GetCustomers()
    {
        var dbResult = db.CPTs.ToList();
        var customers = from customer in dbResult

                        select new
                        {
                            customer.CPT1,
                            customer.MOD,
                            customer.SDESC,
                            customer.FAGE,
                            customer.TAGE
                        };
        return new LargeJsonResult { Data = customers, JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // prepare the data
        var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [{ name: 'CPT1' }, { name: 'MOD' },
            { name: 'SDESC' }, { name: 'FAGE' }, { name: 'TAGE' }, ],
            url: 'dbCPT/GetCustomers'
        };
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
            source: source,
            theme: 'classic',
            columns: [{ text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName',
                width: 250
            }, { text: 'CPT Code', datafield: 'CPT1', width: 150 },
{ text: 'Short Description', datafield: 'SDESC', width: 180 },
{ text: 'FAGE', datafield: 'From Age', width: 200 },
{ text: 'TAGE', datafield: 'To Age', width: 120}]
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
```

If I run dbCPT/GetCustomers directly I get an output file with all the data I'm pulling but nothing will appear in the grid when going to the dbCPT page.

If you need more of my code to help, let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: jqxGrid from probably [jqwidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) and jqGrid are **different** products. So you used wrong tag for your question.

Comment: I know but qjxgrid and qjwidgets were considered a new tag and since I'm new to the site it wouldn't let me use them.  My apologies, jqgrid was the closest they had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made that work.
In the code bellow I'm using jqxDataAdapter but I don't think that it's necessary.

**JavaScript**

```
var source = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [{ name: 'CompanyName' }, { name: 'ContactName' },
    { name: 'ContactTitle' }, { name: 'Address' }, { name: 'City'} ],
    url: 'Customers/GetCustomers'
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    theme: 'classic',
    columns: [{ text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 250 },
                { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'ContactTitle', width: 180 },
                { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 200 },
                { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 120}]
});
```

**C#**

```
public LargeJsonResult GetCustomers2()
{
    var dbResult = db.Customers.ToList();
    var customers = from customer in dbResult
                    select new 
                    { 
                        customer.CompanyName, 
                        customer.ContactName, 
                        customer.ContactTitle, 
                        customer.Address, 
                        customer.City 
                    };
    return new LargeJsonResult { Data = customers, JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Make sure that you're using the last version of the jqxGrid and proper implementation of LargeJsonResult.

Comment: How do we do the same is the computer object also contains a member as key value pair ? need a little help